# static text/image file upload into ms access database using asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, file-upload

I want to file upload functionality with ms access database into asp.net web application. 
Is there any way to creating both the requirement fulfilled?
I have tried with some external resources, but failed to get the exact functionality what i want to implement.. 
The scenario is:
An asp.net web page having file upload functionality with ms access db connection so that i can store file directly into .mdb database file and that must be earlier than ms access 2007 i.e. in .mdb file or we can say using JET 4.0 engine.
Any kind of help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 12 pages with details: http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003031201&page=1   and more tutorials on the internet

Comment: yup i have tried that code but still not able to uplaod file into an access databse.. everything working file but main functionality of uploading and storing is not working

Comment: How many images do you intend to store? You realize that storing images in mdbs has always been considered a really bad idea due to horrible bloat?

Comment: When you say "Main functionality of uploading and storing is not working", what have you tried, and what is going wrong?  It's hard to help someone troubleshoot their code when we can't see it and don't know how what "not working" means.

Comment: Done with the above link stardeveloper.com.... thanks guys for your valuable time... Everything seems fine now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003031201&page=1

That is the final solution of the answer... thanks all